# Checking Data Binding's value in SWT/Jface

Tags: java, data-binding, swt, jface, windowbuilder

I am trying to bind my SWT UI to a test model in Java. The binding works. But the value is exactly the value from the model. So in a case if the model is a boolean and it returns true, it will appear literally as "true" on the UI widget, which isn't what I want to show my users. Is there a way where I can check the bound value before putting into the UI widget? Say if the model returns true, I check if the model value was true then decide to show on my label as "It is correct" otherwise "No it is wrong" if false.

Similarly, in a case if I have a label and I want to bind it to a model that returns the value of an account's credit balance, my label may already have some text that says "Your account has " and I wish I could just append THE_BOUND_VALUE to the label and not have the whole label's value overwritten by the model's value. Here's how I do my bindings:

```
IObservableValue tableViewer_myTestObserveSingleSelection = ViewersObservables.observeSingleSelection(tableViewer_myTest);
    IObservableList tableViewer_myTestDataContentObserveDetailList = BeansObservables.observeDetailList(tableViewer_myTestObserveSingleSelection, "DataContent", TestModelData.class);
    tableViewer_DataContent.setInput(tableViewer_myTestDataContentObserveDetailList);
```

These codes are generated from windowsbuilder pro in eclipse but somehow, I cannot use anything to modify the way bound value to the way I want to display on my UI.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do conversion between types with [Converters](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/databinding/conversion/Converter.html). Take a look at [this example](http://javafact.com/jface/databinding/converter/).

Comment: Thanks for the example. It is really helpful. I am pretty new to Converters. But when put into a table viewer or a component that has a master-detail kind of relationship and its detail is in a form of a list, I don't seem to be able to find a way to put the converters to it. Or am I missing something out? Are there more examples on these UpdateStrategy thing? I find that there are very few examples on this when I google it.

Comment: @Xenon: You can bind a tableviewer using ViewerSupport. Use the viewer's label provider to set how the values in your model are actually displayed. See this: http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.jface.examples.databinding/src/org/eclipse/jface/examples/databinding/snippets/Snippet009TableViewer.java?view=markup